# My roommate keeps putting their stuff on my nightstand without my permission. Is this legal or illegal?

Tags: colorado

I regularly come home to find that my roommate left her stuff on my nightstand without my permission. Is this non-consensual use of my nightstand  prohibited by law? Like maybe theft (depriving me of use of my own property)?

Comment: Is your nightstand located in a shared room?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/

Comment: How is interpersonal.SE a better venue for a question about property rights in a shared space? Obviously that's a better approach to the underlying problem in the vast majority of cases, but it doesn't help answer the actual question.

Comment: @BernhardDöbler I would imagine so because **room**mate, not flatmate.

Comment: If the room is shared, what legal basis do you have to assert that the nightstand is yours? Did you buy it? Or did you subdivide the room and the nightstand stands in your area?

Comment: @Greendrake:  In American English (note that OP is from Colorado) "roommate" can denote someone you share an apartment with, even if you have your own rooms within that apartment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### [Trespass to chattels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trespass_to_chattels)

— which is "intentionally… dispossessing another of the chattel, or **using or intermeddling** with a chattel in the possession of another."

But don't hold your breath re having a valid case. An attempt to sue would likely be dismissed as [de minimis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_minimis). This is just a trivial interpersonal issue.

Answer (score 4):

> Is this non-consensual use of my nightstand prohibited by law? Like maybe theft (depriving me of use of my own property)?

It would not constitute theft because her act does not really deprive you of anything. Exercising your entitlement to the nightstand is as easy as removing from the nightstand her things. At first glance, her habit also seems short of *reasonably* impairing your quiet enjoyment of the unit or other rights a tenant has.

Actionability seems likelier under a legal theory of *trespass* on grounds of her entering your room without permission. But identifying a viable claim requires knowing details which are missing in your description.

Since removal of her things seemingly is something very easy to do (your post does not reflect otherwise), taking legal action for this may backfire for the frivolous nature of the claim.

Comment: De minimis non curat lex.

Comment: Hmm. If the roommate places items on my nightstand, her things are now occupying an area of my nightstand, and she is therefore obstructing my use of the nightstand.

Comment: @moonman239: Unfortunately, the law doesn't care about your nightstand being obstructed, unless you can credibly and believably say "and therefore I was injured/lost money/etc.", which I very much doubt you can get anyone to believe even if true. You need to work things out with your roommate, lock your door, or get a new roommate/apartment.

Comment: @moonman239 "*she is therefore obstructing my use of the nightstand.*" Yes, but that is something you can remedy immediately. From a legal standpoint the simple, non-detailed matter you describe seems inconsequential (again, except *maybe* for trespass) despite your exclusive entitlement to use the nightstand. If she placed some illegal object such as prescription drugs or an unregistered firearm, calling the police would be warranted lest you be mistakenly found in possession thereof. Your description does not reflect anything like that, though.